Import product data(with variants and categories) from Amazon to Odoo
I have an Excel file containing Product data (with product categories with variants) exported from Amazon. the number of products/items in the file is more than 10000 (ten thousand). the problem is all the data is in one file each product has a product category that is sub from another product category and each product has attributes and values. What I want is to extract all the product categories and upload them, extract all the attributes and values upload them, and finally upload the products.
I don't know how to do it any Help?, this is the file URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jE6y01KtjWK_ImNYZiaBq50YxYT8ySVXAvjLteBA4hM/edit?usp=sharing
